# Ionic cordova build windows throw *MSBUILD* error

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, ionic4

When i run `ionic cordova build windows` it throws error like-

`> cordova build windows
ENV var MSBUILDDIR is set C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise
Building project: C:\Users\shail\Desktop\ionic-demo\ionic-4-windows\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj
        Configuration : debug
        Platform      : anycpu
        Buildflags    : /p:AppxBundle=Never
        MSBuildTools  : C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin
buildProject spawn: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild [ 'C:\\Users\\shail\\Desktop\\ionic-demo\\ionic-4-windows\\platforms\\windows\\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj',
'/clp:NoSummary;NoItemAndPropertyList;Verbosity=minimal',
'/nologo', '/p:Configuration=debug', '/p:Platform=anycpu', '/p:AppxBundle=Never'] { stdio: 'inherit' } C:\Users\shail\Desktop\ionic-demo\ionic-4-windows\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj(61,5): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio..Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
No valid MSBuild was detected for the selected target: Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild: Command failed with exit code 1`

is any one can help to resolve this problem.

ionic -v is `4.12.0`
cordove -v is `9.0.0`

**installed platform**
cordova platforn list
`Installed platforms:
  android 8.0.0
  windows 7.0.0`

Using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise

Comment: Hi, after you change the version to 15.0, if it doesn't work, the error message still to be the error MSB4019: The imported project "xxx" was not found? What's the latest error message?

Comment: And as the build window is to call the msbuild tool to build projects. Have you tried to build the project in VS or using msbuild command in developer command prompt for vs2017 locally, what's the result? I need some error message thrown when building it in vs or msbuild locally to further locate the cause of issue:) Any update please feel free to share here. Th!.

Comment: Maybe you can get some help from Farhad_87's solution in [this link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/building-windows-10-app/92416/7). If it's helpful, please give me a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

> According to the error message: The path of your msbuild tool is
>   invalid.

1.As for vs2017, the msbuild you use should be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin` instead of `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin`.

2.Also, v14.0 is for vs2015 while v15.0 for vs2017, please change all 'v14.0' in your setting to 'v15.0' and run it.

Comment: @ShaileshSingh Hi, any update? Have you checked if it can build successfully within VS IDE?